# Transactions over two HTTP function calls to the server

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions

How to lock the database (I am using c# with DbContext) between HTTP calls to my server so nobody in between my two HTTP function calls operates on the database (particularly on one table). Is there any mechanism for that provided by the database (I am using SQLite DB).

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea, and like an XP problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to prevent another user from accessing the database table (do deletes/inserts/updates) while I am doing some deletes/inserts/updates on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a transaction, the database will be locked until you end it. But SQLite is not designed for multiuser environment. If you have the problem you described, you may not be using the right database.